# Failed to do Component Communication with EventEmitters using Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new in Ionic, so basically I am following a tutorial. In the tutorial, the person is specifying the `EventEmitter` type from `<any>` to `<LoginStatus>`, as shown in my code. I have created another class which I have named `LoginResponse` in *login-response.interface.ts*.

So as I create an object which is the optionally named `result` and pass the keys `email` & `uid`, which are also optional; it is giving me this syntax error showing that type `UserCredential` has nothing in common with type `LoginResponse`.

My code for the *login-form.component.ts* is:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

import { Account } from '../../model/account/account.interface';
import { LoginResponse } from '../../model/login/login.response.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-form',
  templateUrl: 'login-form.components.html'
})
export class LoginFormComponent {
  @Output() loginStatus: EventEmitter < LoginResponse > ;
  account = {} as Account;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.loginStatus = new EventEmitter < LoginResponse > ();
  }

  async login() {
    try {
      const result = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.account.email, this.account.password)
      //I am getting nothing in common userCredential Error on the 'result' word
      this.loginStatus.emit(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      this.loginStatus.emit(error);
    }
  }

  navigateToPage(pageName: string) {
    pageName === 'TabsPage' ? this.navCtrl.setRoot(pageName) : this.navCtrl.push(pageName)
  }

}
```

and my *login-response.interface.ts* file code is:

```
export interface LoginResponse {
  result ? : {
    email ? : string;
    uid ? : string;
  }
  error ? : {
    code ? : string;
    message ? : string;
  }
}
```

I am completely new in Ionic 3, so I don't know where I am making any mistake. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where and how exactly are you binding to `loginStatus`? Post the code for that as well.

Comment: Taking `result` as an example, `await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(...)` returns firebaseUser to you which contains email, uid and other fields, it is not `LoginResponse` type.